# Modify the template for Yii 2's error summary?

Tags: php, yii2

Is there anyway to modify the template for `Yii 2`'s [error summary](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#errorSummary%28%29-detail)?

For example I don't want it to show the text "Please fix the following errors:".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out it doesn't seem to really have a template, but that text is part of the header and you can get rid of it like this:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
$form->errorSummary($model, ['header' => '']);
ActiveForm::end();
```

In my case I didn't want a header so I set it to a `blank` value; you can optionally change it to whatever you want.

Optionally you can also extend the `ActiveForm` class and create your own `errorSummary` method to pass in the options by default to the `errorSummary` method in it's parent.